# ASP.Net / C# - missing an assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, assembly-references

[image]
Hi, I am a newbie in C# and visual studio. As Figure1 shown, I am trying to use the classes from other project in similar solution.

For example: I try to write "Using LibraryMS.Framework" at UserDto.cs from "LibraryMS.MasterSetup".

And I get the following error message:

"the type or namespace name 'framework' does not exist in the namespace 'LibraryMS' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

Does anyone know how can I solve this?
Also, do you have any good ASP.net website development online tutorial?

Visual studio version: 2010
.Net Framework 4.0

Thank you.

Comment: Did you reference this LibraryMS.Framework from your LibraryMSMS.Web project?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to C# :) , Unfortunately, that kind of error can't be explained more than that , especially when it comes to custom libraries, all you can get is check in your reference node in Solution section. So an example for you to start is : 1. Check if you have added the reference in references section; 2. Start using it.

As for tutorials I think out there are plenty of websites and books (Professional ASP.NET MVC 5 for ex.), and original asp.net website

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20type%20or%20namespace%20name%20does%20not%20exist%20in%20the%20namespace&rct=j

Comment: Dear Ermir Beqiraj and Tân Nguyễn thanks for the advice, the problem is still there even I add in the LibraryMS.Framework dll. I will keep troubleshoot the problem :)

Answer (score 4):

Its asking you if you missed an assembly reference. So check the references in your class library for LibraryMS.Framework. If you can't find the reference then you can always add it by hitting "Add Reference" then under Reference Manager, click Project and select the class library which you would like to add.

Comment: Dear dotCoder, I have tried and include the "Library.Framework" dll in "Library.MasterSetup" as well but the problem still there. I will try to solve it as I can. Thank you :)

Comment: Hmmm.. That doesn't make sense though

Answer (score 2):

Along these two days, finally I have find out what is going on. The root case is because I am using ASP.NET Empty Web Application instead of using ASP.NET Server Control. Thank you guys. :) now I feel that Programming is a fun thing. Many thx!