# How to put variables into an object inside a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I'm creating a table to output the values of my database's data. During the process, I was able to output, but only the first record. Then I searched for it and noticed that I had to do a list to store all the data and now I'm stuck. I'm pretty sure it's simple, but I'm only starting

I wanted to do this:

```
List<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeVM = new List<EmployeeViewModel>
{
    MovieID = movie.MovieID,
    MovieName = movie.MovieName,
    MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
    MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
    MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
    MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
};

return View(EmployeeVM);
```

so that i can output like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th><b>Movie Name </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Category </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Year </b></th>
        <th><b>Movie Price</b></th>

    </tr>
    @foreach (EmployeeViewModel item in EmployeeVM)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Model.MovieName</td>
            <td>@Model.MovieCategory</td>
            <td>@Model.MovieYear
            <td>@Model.MoviePrice</td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

> "List" does not contain a definition for "MovieName"
>
> "The type or namespace name 'EmployeeViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different issues in your code.

1. *"List" does not contain a definition for "MovieName"*

   - Here you have list of `EmployeeViewModel`, so you need to add instances of `EmployeeViewModel` to the list.

something like,

```
List<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeVM = new List<EmployeeViewModel>

foreach(var movie in movies)
{
  var temp =     new EmployeeViewModel {
        MovieID = movie.MovieID,
        MovieName = movie.MovieName,
        MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
        MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
        MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
        MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
    };

EmployeeVM.Add(temp);
}
```

If you have only one record of `Movie` then directly use single view model of `Employee`

2. *"The type or namespace name 'EmployeeViewModel' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembley reference?)"*

For this issue you need to import library where you defined `EmployeeViewModel`.

something like

```
using Stackoverflow.Sample.EmployeeViewModel;
```

where `Stackoverflow.Sample` is your project and `EmployeeViewModel` is your class

Comment: well, the second part it doesnt, because it is in the cshtml file. It still has errors in the foreach statement

Comment: if it is in .cshtml then try `@using Stackoverflow.Sample.EmployeeViewModel;`. i.e. append `@` before using. please let me know any further issue you are facing

Comment: It says that the using directive is unnecessary

Comment: @foreach (EmployeeViewModel item in EmployeeVM)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.MovieName</td>
            <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
            <td>@item.MovieYear
            <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
        </tr>
    }                                                            At the foreach statement, the EmployeeViewModel and the EmployeeVM has errors, saying that it doesnt exist. Ive tried with var and Model but it was only outputting 1 record

Comment: `EmployeeViewModel` and  `EmployeeVM` are coming from .cs file you need to include class namespace into .cshtml using `@using Stackoverflow.Sample.EmployeeViewModel;`.. this will resolve your problem

Comment: Now it outputs this error "The type or namespace 'EmployeeViewModel' does not exist in the namespace 'WebApplication3.Models '(are you missing an assembly reference?)". Do I need to put another @using in the .cs file?

Comment: This might helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/q/40758885/6299857, If not then just google it or add new question

Answer (score 1):

Your List is a list of **EmployeeViewModel**, so you need to initialize like the below

```
List<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeVM = new List<EmployeeViewModel>
        {   new EmployeeViewModel()
            {
                MovieID = movie.MovieID,
                MovieName = movie.MovieName,
                MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
                MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
                MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
                MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using foreach loop so you should use item object.

```
@foreach (EmployeeViewModel item in EmployeeVM)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.MovieName</td>
        <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
        <td>@item.MovieYear
        <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: also, you may use `@foreach (var item in Model)...`

Comment: for some reason it still has errors in the "EmployeeViewModel" and in the "EmployeeVM"

Answer (score 0):

You should create instances of `EmployeeViewModel` inside list initializer:

```
List<EmployeeViewModel> EmployeeVM = new List<EmployeeViewModel>
{
    new EmployeeViewModel {
        MovieID = movie.MovieID,
        MovieName = movie.MovieName,
        MovieDescription = movie.MovieDescription,
        MoviePrice = movie.MoviePrice,
        MovieCategory = movie.MovieCategory,
        MovieYear = movie.MovieYear
    },
    ///other list items
};
```

Also you should use `@item`(not `@Model`) inside each iteration:

```
@foreach (EmployeeViewModel item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.MovieName</td>
        <td>@item.MovieCategory</td>
        <td>@item.MovieYear
        <td>@item.MoviePrice</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now im getting 2 errors in the second part of the problem. When I try to output, in the foreach statement